# Small data storage: Amazon S3/DynamoDB vs. Windows Azure vs. Google Cloud

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, amazon-dynamodb

**Situation:**

I have a website where users can enter information, save their information, refresh the page and see the information they just entered.

Currently I am using sql database, but planning to moving to some cloud storage service.

1. I store user information in a json doc. This is usually 30 KB or less but worst case could be 900 KB.
2. I want strongly read-after-write consistency.
3. I am expecting json to doc to grow in the future, but not above 1 MB.
4. I want save/load to be as fast as possible (this is least important).

**Investigations:**

1. AWS DynamoDB restricts string to have a maximum size of 400 KB. I can try compress the json doc to meet this requirement but I am afraid in the future document grow to a size that cannot be compressed to 400 KB.
2. AWS S3 can store file up to 5 TB. However, it does not support consistent read after write.

**Question:**

I am not familiar with Windows Azure or Google Cloud. So my questions are:

1. Does Windows Azure / Google Cloud has strongly read-after-write consistency?
2. Does Windows Azure / Google Cloud has any restriction on single string size?
3. I am currently using EC2 hosts as server. What are the upload speed difference among the three? (I guess S3 is faster since I am using EC2?)
4. Are there any other data storage services that supports strong read-after-write consistency, 1 MB single string size, save/load less than 5 sec for 1 MB string?

Comment: Did you check https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency

Comment: There are several Google Cloud products, each of which have their own consistency promises. For small objects like these, you may want Google Cloud Datastore, or if you plan on them getting very large, you may want Google Cloud Storage. Both have pros and cons, but both are strongly consistent when reading a particular object or row directly. Potentially you may also be interested using a higher level service like Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Curiously, SimpleDB has consistent reads and a max response size of 1MB, max size for any single attribute is 1K... so maybe something useful there... But not sure why you'd want to move away from the gold standard of an RDBMS.

Comment: Thanks all for the reply. My final design is to create a new S3 document each time users click save, update DynamoDB to store the new S3 link, remove the old S3 document to free up space. Creating a new document in S3 has strong consistency and saving only a S3 link in DynamoDB won't give me any space issue. Google Cloud Storage is definitely a good choice, but since I am using EC2 hosts I feel like S3+DynamoDB is the best way to go

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough Is there a particular reason to not use Google Cloud Datastore for very large projects (besides the write speed limitation on each entity)?

Comment: No, just a matter of relative strengths. GCS is great for holding many immutable blobs of data with known IDs, but Datastore may be better for this user case: managing mutable, per-user metadata. Many services could handle this particular requirement, but which one is best depends on the exact use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions from Azure's perspective. I am sure someone will answer from Google's perspective as well.

> Does Windows Azure / <del>Google Cloud</del> has strongly read-after-write
>   consistency?

Yes, Azure storage (Blobs, Tables, Queues, Files) follow strong consistency model. If the write is successful, you can immediately read the contents.

> Does Windows Azure / <del>Google Cloud</del> has any restriction on
>   single string size?

Restrictions are there. It depends on the kind of storage you're using. If you're using Azure Blob Storage, for your purpose you would be using `Block Blob` and the maximum size of a block blob can be 200 GB. If you're using Azure Tables (which is Key/Value Pair NoSQL storage), maximum size of an entity can be 1MB. If you're using DocumentDB, [`maximum size of a document can be 512KB`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#documentdb-limits).

> I am currently using EC2 hosts as server. What are the upload speed
>   difference among the three? (I guess S3 is faster since I am using
>   EC2?)

Quite honestly, this is a very broad question as upload speed depends on a number of factors. But yes, having application and data store in the same region has definite advantage from speed perspective as latency would be comparatively lower than if they were in a different region (or different cloud providers). I would not recommend splitting your application and storage in different cloud providers. If possible, put both of them with same cloud provider.

> Are there any other data storage services that supports strong
>   read-after-write consistency, 1 MB single string size, save/load less
>   than 5 sec for 1 MB string?

Again, this is an opinion soliciting question and is quite broad thus I would refrain from answering this question.